# Can I deploy a MERN app whose both frontend folder and backend folder are on the same Github repo?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, deployment, backend

so its my first time deploying an app, I have googled a lot and tried a lot but was not quite able to find the answer. I have a github repo https://github.com/JokubasTolocka/Movie_app which has both frontend and backend folders. During many tries, I have deployed a github page for frontend and everything works as long as I run the backend locally. Whenever I shut down my VScode the github deployments page returns 404 not found. How can I deploy my backend so that I can use this project in my portfolio? Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am also a beginner and was in the same situation, *I still want to know how to deploy from the same repo.*

I did a quick workaround for my case:
I separated both the into different repositories using `git subtree` command,
Check step-by-step instructions here:
[Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475)

Any further help on this question will be appreciated.

Comment: In my case,
Combined Repository: https://github.com/rajats98/Warbler,
After division->
Frontend-only: https://github.com/rajats98/warbler-client, 
Backend-only: https://github.com/rajats98/warbler-server